# Implementing a view with static and scrolling subviews

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uikit

I'm trying to create a view with two subviews, a statically positioned view and a scrollview. The scrollview has an initial position wherein the top of its content meets the bottom of the static view, but it can take up the full screen, overlapping the static view, as it scrolls.

So something like the App Store on iPhone Plus devices, except the scrollview scrolls over the static view, and not under it.

[image: App Store on iPhone 6s Plus]

I'm trying using a scrollview with a `contentOffset` equal to the height of the static view. While this does the trick visually, it breaks touch input. Any touches made even in the `contentOffset` area i.e. The part that shows the static view, are sent to the scrollview, not the static view.

Any workaround to this would be great, as would any alternative configuration of views. All I want is one static view and one scrolling view that scrolls above it, other implementations are fine as well.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so what possibly can be done is you can use a tableView instead.

1) your static view will be at the same position as it is now. The frame origin of the tableView is same as the static view.

2) Give the height of the first cell of the tableView same as the height of the static view.

3) add no view in tableview first cell and give its background color as clear color.

4) Header height of the tableView should be 0.

Or,
If you have buttons in static view, add that view to your blank cell and remove that view when tableview is scrolled.
I think this can lead to your desire view.

Comment: Wouldn’t the first cell of the tableview (the blank one) still receive any touch events, though?

Comment: Unfortunately they will not.